# Incomplete sensitivity list in VHDL with Sigasi editor

Tags: vhdl, sigasi-studio

Currently, I try to develop my VHDL skills and therefore I use the Sigasi plugin for Eclipse to write some VHDL code. Sigasi is a great tool, but there is one thing, which is bothering me, though. Constantly, Sigasi tosses warnings about incomplete sensitivity lists in process definitions, which are not justified from my point of view. One example is the following entity with the corresponding architecture. It's the description of a ring shift register

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity RingShiftReg is
    generic(
        WIDTH : integer := 8
    );
    port(
        clock     : in  std_ulogic;
        reset     : in  std_ulogic;
        set       : in  std_ulogic;
        initValue : in  std_ulogic_vector(WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        value     : out std_ulogic_vector(WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture ringShiftRegArch of RingShiftReg is
    signal innerValue : std_ulogic_vector(WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
begin
    P1: process(clock, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            innerValue <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            if set = '1' then
                innerValue <= initValue;
            end if;
        else
            innerValue <= innerValue(WIDTH - 2 downto 0) & innerValue(WIDTH - 1);
        end if;
    end process;
    value <= innerValue;
end ringShiftRegArch;
```

The Sigasi Linter claims that the sensitivity list of process `P1` is incomplete, because the signal `innerValue` is missing. But in my opinion, it's not necessary to put `innerValue` in the sensitivity list, because it's totally dependent from `clock` and `reset`.

What is correct, now?

Comment: Sigasi. And not necessarily for the reason you might think. innerValue isn't updated while any pending process has yet to resume or suspend. You're implying an event delay on the last assignment. Putting innerValue in the sensitivity list is also a mistake that would cause innerValue to continually update in successive delta cycles (until you hit a limit if implemented).  The assignment is a combinatorial loop.  Why not set innerValue to match the right hand expression in the last assignment in the if statement assigning from initValue? Or declare innerValue as a variable in the process.

Comment: Your process does not model the kind of digital hardware that can be implemented in most technologies (ASIC or FPGA). May I suggest to read carefully the answer I wrote a few hours ago for the very similar question [Match Simulation and Post-Synthesis Behavior in VHDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778965/match-simulation-and-post-synthesis-behavior-in-vhdl/38783500#38783500)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps mean this?

```
elsif rising_edge(clock) then
  if set = '1' then
    innerValue <= initValue;
  else
    innerValue <= innerValue(WIDTH - 2 downto 0) & innerValue(WIDTH - 1);
  end if;
end if;
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it short, your

```
else
  innerValue <= ... 
end if;
```

does not make sense in classical digital hardware because in this context your `else` means:

- `clock` or `reset` (or both) changed, and
- `reset` is not equal to `'1'`, and
- this is not a rising edge of `clock`.

So, it can be:

- a falling edge of `reset`, or
- a falling edge of `clock` while `reset` equals `'0'`.

Probably not what you intended. If it is what you intended, you should try to find another target technology. Classical digital hardware cannot achieve this because there are no multi-clocks, multi-edges, registers in ASIC standard cells libraries or in FPGAs.